# jax-rs: jersey @pathparam to get previous param in one method

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, path-parameter

**How would i get the last path parameter in on method.**

```
@Path("{profile}/articles")
 public getAllArticles(@PathParam("profile") String profile ){

}
@Path("{articleId}")
 public getArticle(@PathParam("articleid") long id ){

}
```

> I know how to get the recent path parameter like `articleId` in method
>   `getArticle`. but i want to get the previous path parameter in the `getArticle` method.
>
> ex: if the URL is `/{profile}/articles/{articleId}`. How would I get values of both `{profile}` and `{articleId}` in same method

PS: I know i can get that by breaking the URL,if I get path from `UriInfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get multiple `@PathParam` if you specified in the `@Path` annotation.

```java
@Path("/{profile}/articles/{articleId: \\d+}")
public Article readArticle(
    @PathParam("profile") final String profile,
    @PathParam("articleId") final long articleId) {

    // "SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE a.profile=:profile AND a.id=:aid"
}
```

I wish I can include any further explanation.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.